# Run simulink model in raspberry pi

Tags: matlab, raspberry-pi, simulink

I want to run simulink model in raspberry pi. I have matlab file system for my system like below image. I want to create model using that matlab files. And then i have to run that model on raspberry pi.

What function block can i use to create that model?

[image]

Comment: Google "Simulink Raspberry Pi" and you will get hundreds of hits showing how to use the two.

Comment: @ Phil Goddard i tried. when i use interpreted matlab function i got "matlab fcn block not supported by the simulink coder" error.  how to solve this?

Comment: What's the _exact_ error message you're getting?  MATLAB Function Block's do support code generation, but only for a subset of the MATLAB language.  You must be doing something specific that isn't supported. See various of the links off the [MATLAB Function Block](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/matlabfunction.html) documentation for a list of limitations.

Comment: @  Phil Goddard I used Interpreted matlab function block. not MATLAB Function Block .

Comment: The Interpreted MATLAB Function Block does not support code generation, and there is no way to make it do so.  Note that only a small portion of MATLAB's functionality is suitable for code generation (whether used with Simulink or not).  If you are using any functionality that cannot be code generated then you are out of luck.  I'd refer back to my initial comment above, and suggest you look at what can be done.